# Javascript: Filter Array by List of Array Index Numbers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Array which contains following data below. I need to filter the list by Array Index number.

The array, does not have array Id number, however, if `filterList` is `[0,2]` it should grab the First and Third Element in the array below.

How can this be done?

```
let filterList = [0,2];

documentPropertyGridData: Array<DocumentPropertyGridData> = new Array<DocumentPropertyGridData>();

let doc1 = new DocumentPropertyGridData();
doc1.documentNumber = '2';
doc1.situsAddress = '123 Oak';

let doc2 = new DocumentPropertyGridData();
doc2.documentNumber = '7';
doc2.situsAddress = '567 3rd Avenue';

let doc3= new DocumentPropertyGridData();
doc3.documentNumber = '9';
doc3.situsAddress = '895 Washington St';

let doc4= new DocumentPropertyGridData();
doc4.documentNumber = '3';
doc34.situsAddress = '894 Forest Road';

this.documentPropertyGridData.push(doc1);
this.documentPropertyGridData.push(doc2);
this.documentPropertyGridData.push(doc3);
this.documentPropertyGridData.push(doc4);
```

Currently using Typescript in Angular Environment, however JavaScript code will work.

Comment: loop **filterList** (like `filterList.forEach(index => {...})`), then push `documentPropertyGridData[index]` into `let result = []`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the filter method of an array to filter based on the index as provided in the filterList.

```js
var arr = [

    {
    documentNumber: '2',
    situsAddress:"123 Oak"
},
  {
    documentNumber: '7',
    situsAddress:"567 3rd Avenue"
},
  {
    documentNumber: '9',
    situsAddress:"895 Washington St"
},
  {
    documentNumber: '3',
    situsAddress:"894 Forest Road"
}
]

var filterList = [0,2];

var result = arr.filter((obj,index) => filterList.includes(index));
console.log(result)

OR 

filterList.map((item) => arr[item]))
```

Comment: would this work also? filterList .map((item) => this.documentPropertyGridData[item]))

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` on `filterList` to get your documents by `index`:

```js
var filterList = [0, 2];
var doc = [

  {
    documentNumber: '2',
    situsAddress: "123 Oak"
  },
  {
    documentNumber: '7',
    situsAddress: "567 3rd Avenue"
  },
  {
    documentNumber: '9',
    situsAddress: "895 Washington St"
  },
  {
    documentNumber: '3',
    situsAddress: "894 Forest Road"
  }
]

console.log(filterList.map(index => doc[index]))
```